# Sorting SQL table by multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, sorting

Assume I have this table named `extable`

```
|--A--|--B--|--C--|
|-----|-----|-----|
|01:21| 4-1 | no  |
|01:28| 4-2 | yes |
|05:53| 3-5 | yes |
|03:34| 9-1 | yes |
|18:48| 9-1 | yes |
|13:01| 9-1 | yes |
|00:17| 7-4 | yes |
|14:24| 4-1 | no  |
|18:19| 4-1 | yes |
|08:02| 7-4 | yes |
|15:21| 7-4 | no  |
|21:23| 3-5 | no  |
|02:57| 4-2 | no  |
|21:03| 4-2 | yes |
|11:31| 4-1 | no  |
```

How would I sort it by time, column A, then column B, then column C, like the following:

```
|--A--|--B--|--C--|
|-----|-----|-----|
|05:53| 3-5 | yes |
|21:23| 3-5 | no  |
|18:19| 4-1 | yes |
|14:24| 4-1 | no  |
|21:03| 4-2 | yes |
|02:57| 4-2 | no  |
|08:02| 7-4 | yes |
|15:21| 7-4 | no  |
|18:48| 9-1 | yes |
|21:56| 9-1 | no  |
```

I want to be able to sort it by the lowest to highest in column B. Then, I want `yes` to be before the `no` option for each entry in column B. The timestamp in column A will be the latest of the `yes` and `no` entries. I feel like me explaining it is a lot less effective than the example above.

I know I can do this: `ORDER BY column B, column C, column A;`, but this will pull every single entry out of the original table. I only want the latest ones by the timestamp in column A, if that makes sense. Notice how `9-1` has four entries in the original table, but only the latest `yes` and `no` options were pulled for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two requirement: 1) Order the results as listed 2) Keep only the most recent yes/no values for each column "B"

The `ORDER BY` clause is pretty straightforward. The only change is sticking "DESC" after the `C` field in the clause so that `yes` shows up first.

The second requirement can be solved using a Window Function to group the rows in the result set by `B` and `C`, and then sort it by `A` numbering the results in each group. Then we just keep anything ranked as `1`

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            A,
            B,
            C,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B, C ORDER BY A DESC) as keeprank
        FROM <table>
    ) t1
WHERE keeprank = 1
ORDER BY A, B, C DESC
```